# Changing CURRENT_TIMESTAMP value based on timezone in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to migrate our mysql server from shared hosting to local server.

Current server is in MST time zone and the values for the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in databsse is stored as -7:00 GMT.

Now I want to move complete application on dedicated server in India. Also want to convert the  date values stored in -7:00 GMT to +5:30 GMT.

I can accomplish this task of updating the dates by writing script to update the time, however I would like to know if is there any way I can do this from database itself (at time of import  or while exporting itself)

**mysql version 5.0.96-log. I am not getting option export timestamp in UTC.**

Answer (score 3):

When using mysqldump, set the flag: --tz-utc to force all timestamps to be exported as UTC. ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_tz-utc ). Note here **--tz-utc is enabled by default**. So you should have to do nothing: but test first :)

If just working with timestamps on the server you don't have to do anything to convert them, from the documentation on TIMESTAMP post MySQL 4.1 ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/timestamp.html ):

> "values still are stored in UTC, but are **converted from the current
>   time zone for storage, and converted back to the current time zone for
>   retrieval**. As long as the time zone setting remains constant, you
>   get back the same value you store. If you store a TIMESTAMP value, and
>   then change the time zone and retrieve the value, the retrieved value
>   is different from the value you stored."

This is easy to test:

1. Save a timestamp to your table
2. Change the server's timezone
3. Retrieve it: the return value should reflect the new timezone.

So another option is you could just have both the servers set to the same timezone while doing the export / import, than set them back to the correct timezone(s) after it is complete, but note with MySQLDump this should not be necessary.

Comment: Thanks.

I think I missed to inform that I am trying migrate the data by taking dump from one server and importing it on other. So while importing the dump, server won’t be able to determine the timezone of the exported dump unless specified explicitly.

Comment: Updated to reflect that question as well.

Comment: Thanks. Setting same time zone for both server for import and export and changing the timezone after the transaction seems best option.

Comment: Should not even have to do that - mysqldump should handle everything for you as-is.

Answer (score -3):

General syntax

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(<column_name>, INTERVAL HOUR);
```

for changing to UTC to MST

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 HOUR);
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: Indeed, this is not an answer.